# Google Apps Script (Docs) ListItem and setting ListIds

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I see that you can set two `ListItems` as belonging to the same list via `listItem2.setListId(listItem1)`;

The method signature is `ListItem.setListId(ListItem listItem)`

I can't find any documentation on how to arbitrarily create a totally new list. For example I want to do something like

`listItem2.setListId("my-custom-list-id");`

or even

`listItem2.setListId(new ListId());`

What am I missing?

Comment: [`.setListId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item) is expecting listItem type not a "my-custom" string. Might help to know why you want to set a custom id.

Comment: @BryanP thanks for comment. I am building an add-on that parses another format into Google Docs. There is the possibility that there are two lists directly adjacent to one another – one may be ordered while the other is unordered. In that case, if I keep adding ListItems, they will be one or the other list type. I want to programmatically ensure that a new list (and list type) has begun

Comment: I have a similar problem - I have a script merging several documents together, which works fine, but as the ListIDs google creates are non-random, all the lists in all the docs things they are part of the same list.  - it would be useful to be able to set this directly

Comment: For a solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37278889/197789